# Elasticsearch installed on Azure Linux VM isnt't reachable

Tags: linux, azure, elasticsearch, firewall

I have configured an Elasticsearch instance on an Azure Linux VM instance, as described [here](http://code972.com/blog/2014/07/74-the-definitive-guide-for-elasticsearch-on-windows-azure). The service is running smoothly as I can check by issuing a curl command.

But since this is an exploratory server instance I want to open 9200 port on the VM to be available for any external client. I opened 9200 and 9300 ports on the VM using iptables. In addition I created an Azure Endpoint, as described for example [here](http://thomasardal.com/running-elasticsearch-in-a-cluster-on-azure/), that maps TCP request on public port 9200 to a machine's private port 9200.

However, the machine and port is not reachable from outside. I am certainly missing either VM or VPN configuration, I just can't figure out what else to I need to configure.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a few hours on this issue I decided to switch from Azure beta portal (portal.azure.com) to an old portal (manage.windowsazure.com) and created an endpoint there. And then it worked! So it must be something that malfunctions in the new Azure Portal pre-release.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest java, and do the following:

You have to edit the elasticsearch config file by using:

```
sudo vi /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

And set the following parameters:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0

http.port: 9200
```

Now add this directly under `http.port:9200` headline:

```
script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on
```

Finally, make sure you open BOTH PORTS 9200 and 9300 from VM Endpoints or Network Security Group inbound.

I have it functioning normally using this config.